# Error:The method assertEquals(String, String) is undefined for the type Object

Tags: java, junit

Even after imported import static org.junit.Assert.*;getting below error

Error:The method assertEquals(String, String) is undefined for the type Object

Comment: please add a sample code block. It will help to understand an issue

Comment: It means that you are passing null value in the assertEquals() method instead of string.

Comment: Additional information to @SubanDhyako which is right: The method `assertEquals` can compare different types. Since this method is generic implemented there is just 1 Rule - both parameters need to have the same type so they can be compared by object content/reference (depends on `hashCode()`). In this case 1 param is recognized as String ince there is a given value. I would guess your expected value. The other one is NULL so the type is not recognized and the method `assertEquals(T,T)` does not match.

If NULL is spected use `asserIsNull` instead

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after adding code

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
```

but I tried with this import static

```
org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
```

it worked for me.